# Java: Using two Readers on one InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader, buffering

My application can edit a type of text file called a *TDAEntry*. Each such entry is based on another type of file that describes its format, called a *TDAForm*. The very first line in a *TDAEntry* text file is the name of the form it belongs to, and then the rest of the data (in text form) follows.

For opening such a file now, here is my code, simplified:

```
InputStream entryInput = new FileInputStream(file);

BufferedReader entryReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(entryInput)); // PROBLEMATIC #1

String formName = entryReader.readLine();

TDAForm form = new TDAForm(formName);

// create an entry with the right form and the data which follows in entryInput
TDAEntry entry = new TDAEntry(form, entryInput); // PROBLEMATIC #2
```

Here's the problem. When reading the source code for `InputStreamReader`, you'll end up reading the code of this class:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.java#StreamDecoder.read(char%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint)

which is buffered, which means that it reads about 8000 bytes ahead. This causes the `InputStream` at line "Problematic #2" to be empty and in the wrong spot, while I want it to continue as if only the very first line of the file had been read. Inside the constructor of *TDAEntry* I might want to construct another kind of reader on the stream, or do something else.

One obvious solution is writing a new decoder that doesn't eat up the bytes ahead. But I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do this. How would you tackle the problem, or do you suggest another programming structure to accomplish the same thing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The best way to do this is kill the buffered reader and read in the first line manually. You can't control how the buffered reader buffers without re-implementing it.

Comment: This won't work, because InputStreamReader is actually also buffered, as it turned out. I unfortunately found out after writing my own line-reading reader, and the bytes were still getting buffered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass in the reader.  it will keep reading where it left off:

```
TDAEntry entry = new TDAEntry(form, entryReader);
```

Comment: I thought about this, but I might want to construct the TDAEntry on another kind of stream, which isn't a reader. But perhaps I should make a separate constructor for that, or something?

Comment: Yes you can have 2 constructors, one that takes a Reader and one that takes an InputStream or whatever else you want.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct for now, as it's the solution I'm going to run with. Should've realized I could have more than one constructor earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try wrapping your FileInputStream into a BufferedInputStream since the buffered version supports mark() and reset().

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to limit the buffer, you don't need to write your own class. You can use the second constructor, i.e. `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entryInput), 20);` to limit the buffer size.

Not that this is necessarily the best way to handle this problem. Basically switching streams in mid-air is quite a bad idea. You could create your own InputStream implementation that reads both the header and the entries.

Comment: The first solution won't work, because InputStreamReader is actually also buffered. But your second idea is interesting, although it seems slightly wasteful not to use the character decoding abilities of a Reader should I make my own InputStream.